# Adding code might invalidate answers

Tags: discussion, edits

In a rush, I asked a question with fairly concise code blocks and probably not enough background information. Later, when I had time, I added in and fleshed out the code but I was worried that my new code would invalidate some of the answers I had received.

In this case, should I still add my code? Some of the older answers might be flagged as incorrect when they just simply didn't have enough information at the time. I don't want to hurt other users in such a manner. While I could add comments to each answer, I feel that adds too much noise as well.

Alternately, should I consider deleting my question and asking it again?

P.S. To clarify, I'm talking about adding code to my own question, not others.

Comment: I would say, add your code-blocks. If you clarify your question, rather than making it a moving target, it's acceptable. Ideal? No. Might some dislike it enough to downvote for it? Perhaps. And ideally you should not do things in a rush and leave them incomplete. But hey, it happens.

Answer (score 2):

Don't delete your question, not unless you want to come back here begging the community to undo the automated question ban, which no one can do. ;)  Of course, this assumes you delete a lot of stuff or get downvoted a lot and don't fix your posts, but still, deletion is for content that is of no value. In your case, you can make it *really* valuable... so don't delete it. :)

The best thing to do is what you're already doing. Edit your post and improve it. If certain answers change because they were answered with lack of information, then comment on them.

Answerers have the responsiblity to seek clarification if there are unknowns. This is precisely what comments are for. These users should have either asked you for more information or voted to close your post, if it was extremely vague. Many won't mind coming back to update or help you out further, as many people here just enjoy helping others.

In short, don't let a few answers stop you from turning something so-so into something great. :) Consider that, even if the answers aren't updated by the posters, you'll likely get other, better answers, and that's what Stack Overflow is about. Good luck!